# Doing Ajax calls from jQuery with mocking

Tags: jquery, ajax, mocking

I want to make an ajax call in jquery which will bring a picture and texts on the side (actually it is a profile picture and little info about that particular person).And have a link underneath that picture.But i dont know what data type to use in $.ajax()?And where do i put the link in html?Also i am mocking the data so i dont know in what file to put the picture and text.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to do any special processing, consider using [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/), which wraps .ajax and loads HTML into a specified container into your page.  Your server side mock script should expose HTML which provides the picture and text, hardcoded, from a database, or what have you.

The below assumes your side area where you want to load these items contains a div with the id of `sideContainer`.

```
$("#sideContainer").load("/path/to/mock/as/html/");
```

Comment: so the url "/path/to/mock/as/html/" should be of what file type?@justkt

Comment: @David - how do you want to deliver your content?  It could be static .html or if you want it to be dynamic use your source language - just return an HTTP header indicating that it's HTML.